# Is it required to specify Maven Surefire Plugin in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Why is this pom.xml can run `mvn test` without specified maven surefire plugin?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lester</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-basics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit-basics</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What is the difference of putting the plugin in the pom.xml and not putting it?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I remember that `maven-surefire-plugin` will automatically run your unit tests (for `package`) if selected as a part of the build cycle, whereas without it you would need to manually specify the `test` goal yourself when running maven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify the maven-surefire-plugin in your pom, your build will pick up its version as specified in Maven, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html
These versions haven't been updated for a while to ensure that an upgrade of Maven won't impact your build because of a different plugin version.
Most likely these versions will be updated with a next major release of Maven. So it all depends on the lifetime of your project and if it is a private project. If it has a long lifetime, better to lock those plugins to a specific version, so you don't depend on the Maven version anyone uses to build the project.